# variable inside int in c giving exceptional output

Tags: c

In below given program if I put n=0, then the program is giving right answer but if I write n instead of n=0, the program is giving me wrong answer. If I put k=10 then output is 94 but the correct answer is 55. Why it is adding additional 39?

```c
int main(){
    // program to calculate the sum of 'n' numbers
    int i=1,k,n;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&k);
    do{
        n+=i;
        i++;
    }while(i<=k);
    printf("The sum is: %d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `n` initially?

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is adding a value to the current value of `n`, but you never set the initial value of `n`.  That means its value is **indeterminate**, and reading an indeterminate value (in this case when you add to it), when the variable in question never had its address taken triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Initialize `n` to 0 so you have a valid starting point.

```
int i=1, k, n=0;
```